# Help with Tangent Plane to Graph of 3 Variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have this true/false question for homework and can't seem to answer it.

> The following statement is nonsense: “the tangent plane to
>   the graph of $f(x, y, z)=x^2 + y^2 + z^2$
>   at $(x, y, z) = (1, 2, 3)$ is
>   $2x + 4y + 6z = 28$”.
>
> Modify it to make it a true statement.

So, I calculated the equation of the tangent plane to the graph, and I get that very function. Is it nonsense, or is it already true?

Comment: You're missing a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Randall nails it in his comment to your question. The graph of $f(x,y,z)$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^4$. The given plane, however, lives in $\mathbb R^3$, so can’t possibly be tangent to the surface. You need to either change it to an equation of a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^4$ or have the surface be given implicitly by $f(x,y,z)=const.$, i.e., use a level surface of the function $f$.